# Cookie can NOT be set anymore and site unavailable

Tags: cookie, ce-1.9.2.3

I can't access the frontend of my site
http://magento.p292682.webspaceconfig.de/
anymore.
However, I was able to access the site from a machine that had a cookie saved from that site (10 hours earlier). Deleting cookies from that machine made the site unavailable again so I'm 100% sure that it is a cookie problem.
I don't know what happened but cookies are not set anymore (I think that this is the problem) and therefore the site is not available anymore.

Answer (score 0):

if you have a cookie problem issue u can  System menu>Configuration>Web button in the General section on the left>Session Cookie Management panel on the right. When you expand the panel you'll see an option Cookie Lifetime. Change the number to whatever you want (it's in seconds) and click on the Save Config button

Comment: This is already set to 3600

Comment: Did you set a cookie domain? And did you check your Magento logs in `var/log/`?

Comment: no I didnt. What should I check it for and which domain should I set it to?

Comment: If you didn't set it, then that won't be the problem. Check if there is anything related in your exception.log or system.log. It might be an idea to rename the old files, try to login or something and check if a new file is created and check the contents.

Comment: please increase 3600 to 9600